# Bash script not waiting on read

Tags: bash

I'm trying to run commands as another user and read input as that user.  For some reason the script doesn't pause on the `read` command, I'm unsure as to why.  Here's an example of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
username='anthony'
sudo -H -u "$username" bash << 'END_COMMAND'

# Commands to be run as new user
# -------------------------------

echo "#!  Running as new user $USER..."


echo "#!  Gathering setup information for $USER..."
echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo -n "Enter your email and press [ENTER]: "
read email
END_COMMAND

echo "Done"
```

Any ideas as to why this isn't stopping on `read name` or `read email`?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`read` is reading from stdin, and `bash` is inheriting its stdin from sudo, which is coming from the heredoc.  If you want it to come from somewhere else, you need to be explicit.  For example:

```
bash  3<&0 << 'END_COMMAND'
...
read <&3
...
```

This does not work with sudo, however, since sudo closes the non-standard file descriptors.  But sudo does not close stderr, so if you can get away with reusing that file descriptor, you might be able to do:

```
sudo -H -u "$username" bash 2<&0 << 'END_COMMAND'
...
read -u 2 email
...
```

But it's probably much safer to do:

```
sudo -H -u "$username" bash << 'END_COMMAND'
...
read email < /dev/tty
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you have this script check if it's running as sudo, and if it's not, exec itself with sudo?

```
#!/bin/bash
username='anthony'

if [[ -z "${SUDO_USER}" ]]; then
    exec sudo -H -u "${username}" -- $0
fi

echo "
# Commands to be run as new user
# -------------------------------
"
echo "#!  Running as new user $USER..."

echo "#!  Gathering setup information for $USER..."
echo -n "Enter your name and press [ENTER]: "
read name
echo -n "Enter your email and press [ENTER]: "
read email
```